# Why flutter button stays under keyboards when keyboard appears

Tags: flutter

i want to push the page up when keyboard is on. i have next page button bottom of my page (for now its bottomnavigationbar) but when i filling fields and keyboard is on next page button stays under keyboard, i want to keyboard pushes up the bottomnavigationbar and always seen

```
Scaffold(
body : Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
           ..mywidgets
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
bottomNavigationBar: nextButtonWidget()
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing widgets inside BottomNavigationBar will show your widgets at the bottom of the screen regardless of whether screen is scrolled or not.

To scroll your button dynamically up,

Place your nextButtonWidget in bottomSheet.

```
bottomSheet: nextButtonWidget()
```

Answer (score 1):

put your nextButtonWidget inside Column. Not as bottomNavigationBar.